# Find the quantity of such numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> A six digits number $abcdef$ satisfy:
>
> 1. Each digits is non zero.
> 2. $ab+cd+ef$ is even.
>
> Find the number of such six digits numbers.

The answer given is $56^3+3 \cdot 56 \cdot 25^2$,  why we need to multiply that 3? Thank you.

Comment: Obviously I tried and get the answer $56^3+56*25^2$.

Comment: We can help you better if you share the details of your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $ab + cd + ef$ is even then either

- $ab,cd,ef$ are all even
- exactly 2 of $ab,cd,ef$ are odd and one is even.

In the second part, you have a choice which one should be even, and there are exactly 3 possibilities. That explains the $3$ in the answer.

Comment: AH HA! Thanks!!